# 2.83 Cycles texture baking coming out weird

Tags: texture-baking

Blender 2.83.5

I've got some complicated materials in my model that I'd like to try and bake so that render times aren't as crazy.  Process outlined below

Selected my mesh, and created a new image texture in the shader editor
[image]

Unwrapped the mesh and scaled it to my liking
[image]

Made sure the new image texture node was selected and then hit bake.  Bake parameters are all defaults; combined > all influences checked > 16px margin with clear image checked.  This is what comes out.  The mesh is all wonky.
[image]

I suspect it has something to do with how I've UV unwrapped it but even when I do a simple rectangle (the floor) it comes out wonky as well.

No bake:
[image]

Bake:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about the engine, but the floor bake looks...correct.  It's applying the shadow to the floor for objects that are there on the render.  What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi Kirbinator,

The shadows are there but the texture and coloring are incorrect- which I presume they shouldn't be with the combined bake.